# Porque não faz Update?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: Se buscar so um assim e rodar o foreach ele faz o update mas se tiver mais ele ja não faz mais...][image: Ai na imagem ele não altera nenhum e não da nenhum erro] 
Se buscar so um assim e rodar o foreach ele faz o update mas se tiver mais ele ja não faz mais... Mas se tiver mais de um como na outra imagem ele não altera e não da erro o que eu faço?

Porque não faz update ? ... Ele **não da erro** nenhum so **não faz o update**

```
//Prepra ligacao php mysql
$stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM sol_camiseta 
                             WHERE cod_nome_aluno = :id' );
//Atribui o paramentro ao $_GET['id'] que é o id que esta na url e coloca ele no prepare acima
$stm->bindValue( ':id', $_GET['id'] );
//Executa o pdo
$stm->execute();

//Tranforma o consulta em matriz
$consultas = $stm->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
include 'views/listar.php'; 

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'conexao.php';

//Pega o id da url
if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['id'] ) ){

if ( $_POST )  {
    //Ligação php mysql
    $stm = $pdo->prepare( "UPDATE sol_camiseta 
                           SET data_pagamento = :data_pagamento, 
                           data_retirada = :data_retirada
                           WHERE id = :id");

    //Atribui o paramentro ao $_POST['e a referecia onde ele esta'] e coloca ele no prepare acima

    $stm->bindValue( ':data_pagamento', $_POST['data_pagamento'] );
    $stm->bindValue( ':data_retirada', $_POST['data_retirada'] );
    $stm->bindValue( ':id', $_GET['id'] );

    //Executa o pdo
    $stm->execute();

    //depois de executar o header o rediciona para outro local
    header( "Refresh:5, index.php" );
}
}



    <fieldset>
    <legend>Camiseta</legend>
        <table>
            <?php foreach ( $consultas as $consulta ) : ?>
            <form action='pagarcamiseta.php?id=<?php echo $consulta['id']; ?>'  method='post'>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tipo:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['tipo']; ?></td>
                    <td>Cor:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['cor']; ?></td>
                    <td>Tamanho</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['tamanho']; ?></td>
                    <td>Quantidade</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['qtd']; ?></td>
                    <td>Valor</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['valor']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data Pedido:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['data_pedido']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data Pagamento:</td>
                    <td><input type='date' name='data_pagamento' value='<?php if ( isset( $_POST['data_pagamento'] ) ) echo $_POST['data_pagamento']; else echo $consulta['data_pagamento']; ?>'></td>
                    <td>Data Retirada:</td>
                    <td><input type='date' name='data_retirada' value='<?php if ( isset( $_POST['data_retirada'] ) ) echo $_POST['data_retirada']; else echo $consulta['data_retirada']; ?>'></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Salvar" /></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <td><a href='index.php'>Voltar</a></td>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Inclua um `error_reporting(E_ALL);` no início do script, que deve aparecer algum erro.

Comment: No começo logo depois do <?php ?

Comment: Isso, no começo logo depois do `<?php`.

Comment: Não apareceu nenhum erro

Comment: Ele roda o FOREACH mas se tiver dois ele ja não faz o update

Comment: Mas ele tá conectando com o banco? Você precisa pegar o erro ... [Neste link](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3638/php-pdo-como-se-conectar-ao-banco-de-dados.aspx) você pode ver como pegar o erro da conexão com o PDO.

Comment: Pior que ele não ta dando erro na conexão...

Comment: Viu a imagem que eu coloquei ali e quero que quando eu clicar no salvar ele altere as datas conforme o que eu colocar... o que vc me aconselha?

Comment: Oque eu nao entendi é o cod_nome_aluno... ele faz parte da tabela sol_camisetas certo? Mas ele é a chave primaria da tabela?

Comment: Então cara, eu não manjo de PDO, uso o mySQLi, mas tenta colocar `if (!$stm) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}` ou `$stm -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` pra ver se aparece algum erro... [fonte](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/474463-resolvidorecuperando-erros-mysql-com-pdo/)

Comment: A chave primaria é o ID da tabela

Comment: vou tentar colocar aque

Comment: coloca depois de `$stm->execute();`

Comment: tinha um erro no primeiro exemplo, tenta assim: `if (!$stm) { echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n"; print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); }`

Comment: Entao camarada... o problema esta ai... vc esta fazendo um looping que aplica varios forms conforme a quantidade de camiseta por id de aluno... vc tem que incluir a chave primaria em cada form tbm para que quando a pessoa salvar o pdo vai saber qual registro é... eu acho que eh isso

Comment: Verifique se o id a ser alterado existe e também veja se o auto commit está ligado

Comment: Então alterei o código ontem... ao fiz ele chamar pelo o id mas ai ele so chama o primeiro id e como se ele incluísse o primneiro id, ai todas as linhas idependente qual salvar eu clicar vai ser o primeiro id do foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se houver várias camisetas para o aluno, haverão um monte de campos com o mesmo nome, por exemplo 'data_pagamento', há um para cada camiseta.

O PHP aceita colocar o nome dos campos como array, então é possível separar para cada linha do banco de dados, por exemplo com o id da linha da camiseta, mas aí acho que precisa um pouco de trabalho a mais.

Obs.:

1. Você está criando e executando um statement fora do `if`, depois um dentro do `if` com a mesma query do de fora, depois, no loop `for`, está jogando fora o resultado do statement de dentro do `if` quando atribui à variável que guardava o resultado, cada linha do resultado do statement de fora do `if`.
2. Eu não conhecia esta construção do foreach, só conhecia com chaves.
3. O trecho de código inserido possui delimitadores não fechados, então a resposta pode ser imprecisa.
4. No exemplo abaixo, o campo `sol_camiseta_id` seria o id da linha da tabela que você quer atualizar, não sei qual é o nome correto, mas deve haver um campo id único para cada linha. Se não houver, substitua o seu DBA depois peça para o novo ajudar a resolver.
5. Havendo o campo `sol_camiseta_id`, o campo `cod_nome_aluno` seria somente para garantir que um aluno não consiga manipular os dados e alterar valor para camisetas de outros alunos.

Por exemplo:

```
...
$i = 0;
foreach
  ...
                        <td>Data Pagamento:<input type="hiden" name="cId[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $sol_camiseta_id; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input type='date' name='data_pagamento[<?php echo $i; ?>]' value='<?php if ( isset( $_POST['data_pagamento'] ) ) echo $_POST['data_pagamento']; else echo $consulta['data_pagamento']; ?>'></td>
                        <td>Data Retirada:</td>
                        <td><input type='date' name='data_retirada[<?php echo $i; ?>]' value='<?php if ( isset( $_POST['data_retirada'] ) ) echo $_POST['data_retirada']; else echo $consulta['data_retirada']; ?>'></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Salvar" /></td>
  $i++;
  ...
endforeach;
...
```

Cada campo que receber será um array, então deve executar o statement para cada conjunto de dados dos arrays, se tudo correr bem e o usuário não tentar quebrar seu sistema, todos os campos serão arrays com o mesmo tamanho e índices corretos.

```
...
$stm = $pdo->prepare( "UPDATE sol_camiseta 
                       SET data_pagamento = :data_pagamento, 
                       data_retirada = :data_retirada
                       WHERE cod_nome_aluno = :cod_nome_aluno
                         AND sol_camiseta_id = :sol_camiseta_id");

$stm->bindValue( ':data_pagamento', $data_pag );
$stm->bindValue( ':data_retirada', $data_ret );
$stm->bindValue( ':cod_nome_aluno', $cod_aluno );
$stm->bindValue( ':sol_camiseta_id', $sol_cam_id);

$cod_aluno = $_GET['id']; // este campo é sempre igual
foreach ($_POST['cId'] as $i => $sol_cam_id) { // campo id definido aqui
  $data_pag = $_POST['data_pagamento'][$i]; // campo data pagamento
  $data_ret = $_POST['data_retirada'][$i]; // campo retirada
  $stm->execute();
}
...
```

Comment: Vou tentar muito obrigado, acho que vai resolver, assim minha tabela tem o id ontem consegui reformular um pouco alterando a chada do get pelo id da linha mas não deu muito certo vou alterar o codigo da minha pergunta ai vc da uma olhada

Answer (score 1):

**Deu certo fbiazi Vlw mesmo vou colocar o codigo final aque**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'conexao.php';

//Pega o id da url
if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['id'] ) ){

if ( $_POST )  {
    $stm = $pdo->prepare( "UPDATE sol_camiseta 
                           SET data_pagamento = :data_pagamento, 
                           data_retirada = :data_retirada
                           WHERE cod_nome_aluno = :cod_nome_aluno
                           AND id = :id");

    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $id) { // campo id definido aqui
    $data_pagamento = $_POST['data_pagamento'][$i]; // campo data pagamento
    $data_retirada = $_POST['data_retirada'][$i]; // campo retirada

    $stm->bindValue( ':data_pagamento', $data_pagamento );
    $stm->bindValue( ':data_retirada', $data_retirada );
    $stm->bindValue( ':cod_nome_aluno', $_GET['id'] );
    $stm->bindValue( ':id', $id);


    $stm->execute();
    }

<fieldset>
    <legend>Camiseta</legend>
        <table>
            <?php foreach ( $consultas as $consulta ) : ?>
            <form action='pagarcamiseta.php?id=<?php echo $consulta['cod_nome_aluno']; ?>'  method='post'>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tipo:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['tipo']; ?></td>
                    <td>Cor:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['cor']; ?></td>
                    <td>Tamanho</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['tamanho']; ?></td>
                    <td>Quantidade</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['qtd']; ?></td>
                    <td>Valor</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['valor']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data Pedido:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $consulta['data_pedido']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>Data Pagamento:<input type="hidden" name="id[<?php echo $consulta['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $consulta['id']; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type='date' name='data_pagamento[<?php echo $consulta['id']; ?>]' value='<?php if ( isset( $_POST['data_pagamento'] ) ) echo $_POST['data_pagamento']; else echo $consulta['data_pagamento']; ?>'></td>
                    <td>Data Retirada:</td>
                    <td><input type='date' name='data_retirada[<?php echo $consulta['id']; ?>]' value='<?php if ( isset( $_POST['data_retirada'] ) ) echo $_POST['data_retirada']; else echo $consulta['data_retirada']; ?>'></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Salvar" /></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <td><a href='index.php'>Voltar</a></td>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```